# WebGL semi-transparent appears white

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, alpha, alphablending

I am having a problem with WebGL. Semi-transparent textures appear semi-transparent, but they're also getting white, color from the texture isn't considered while rendering...

That's what I've set:

```
gl.blendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SRC_ALPHA, BlendingFactorDest.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

What are the possible solutions?

Comment: Is using multitexturing the only solution? How could it be done using fragment shader?

Comment: This is way too vague. Please post a complete code sample, preferable with image of the problem so we can see what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Typically if white appears unexpectedly in a WebGL scene, it's blending in from the CSS background of the web page itself (which defaults to white unless you change it).

In other words, with the default WebGL settings, any shader that writes alpha values less than 1.0 to the color buffer will make the `<canvas>` itself become translucent and show the web page's background.  I believe you can change the [WebGLContextAttributes](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/#WEBGLCONTEXTATTRIBUTES) settings to disable this behavior, or just make sure your shaders always output alpha values of 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

For me setting these WebGL context attributes solved the issue:

```js
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl', {
  alpha: true,
  premultipliedAlpha: false,
});
```

Without `premultipliedAlpha: false` WebGL rendered not fully transparent pixels as white, instead of having opacity like `0.1`.

When WebGL `premultipliedAlpha` disabled, pixels rendered at proper opacity level.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable alpha blending before setting the blend function:

```js
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl", {alpha: false}); // css background shows when alpha is on
gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many combinations to get the correct output in Safari. Eventually I missed to unpack the premultiply alpha package.

```js
let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2', { premultipliedAlpha: true })
gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL, true)
```

No other blend settings were necessary. Tested in Safari 16.6 and iOS Safari 16.6.